# How do I force a cell to time-out in google colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Sometimes when i am running multiple notebooks i forget that some of them have drive mounts. I realize this many hours later that the notebook has blocked on the mount cell, and my GPU instance has been wasted.

Is there any way to put a timeout around a drive mount cell so that the notebook gives an error if i dont enter the code within that time?